# CDAP converting Dates in this format "/Date(1577746800000+0100)/" to simple date

Tags: cdap

Hello i would like to convert dates in this format /Date(1577746800000+0100)/ to simple date using CDAP. someone can help me?
thanks

example of date

```
/Date(1577746800000+0100)/
/Date(1570572000000+0200)/
/Date(1558821600000+0200)/
/Date(1546297200000+0100)/
/Date(1546297200000+0100)/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using wrangler. Since the data is of fixed length, we can extract the timestamp from the string. At the bottom of the screen, you see a console where you can type in instruction.

```
cut-character <column-name> <destination-column-name> 7-19
```

Then we can parse this column to date by:

```
parse-timestamp :<destination-column-name> 'milliseconds'
```

and finally format the result to a format that you like:

```
format-date :<destination-column-name> 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm'
```

Hope that helps!